# How to call C# event from VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I have a C# class library. In that class I have declared an event as a property

```
private static event MouseEventHandler s_MouseClick;
public static event MouseEventHandler MouseClick
{
    add
    {
        s_MouseClick += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        s_MouseClick -= value;
    }
}
```

I have another project written in VB.net, On click of a button I want to do something like this:

```
cls.MouseClick += cls_MouseClick;

void cls_MouseClick(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
}
```

This is how I would do it in C#. But how do I do it in VB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VB, to register an event handler use `AddHandler`:

```vb
AddHandler cls.MouseClick, AddressOf cls_MouseClick
```

Use `RemoveHandler` to unregister the event handler.

Alternatively, you can use a declarative syntax. That is: declare the member as follows:

```vb
Private WithEvents cls As YourClassType
```

And declare the handler like this:

```vb
Private Sub cls_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cls.MouseClick
End Sub
```

Now you do not need to register the handler manually.

Comment: Hi K...
Thanks for your reply. My problem is solved.

Thanks again
Umang